# Error en FTP al ingresar usuario y contraseña con Python y que vuelva a solicitar los datos

Tags: python

Estoy intentado hacer una conexión por *FTP* y funciona, pero ahora el problema es que si ingreso la contraseña o usuario incorrectos, termina el programa con un error obviamente y como es un servidor en mi trabajo tienen los usuarios y contraseñas pero tengo acceso a esos datos.

```
from ftplib import FTP 
import getpass

IP = input("Direccion IP: ")
print ("Conectado a "+ IP)
ftp = FTP (IP)
usu = input("Usuario: ")
psw=getpass.getpass("Contraseña: ")
ftp.login(user=usu,passwd=psw)
print(ftp.login(user=usu,passwd=psw))
ftp.quit()
```

Traté de usar el `try` y `except` con el error de:

> Traceback (most recent call last):

Hice esto al inicio del código anterior, pero no funciona bien.

```
IP = input("Direccion IP: ")
print ("Conectado a "+ IP)
ftp = FTP (IP)
usu = input("Usuario: ")

while True:
    try:
        psw=getpass.getpass("Contraseña: ")
        break
    except:
        print("Contraseña incorrecta")
```

Comment: Para empezar estás llamando dos veces a [`ftp.login()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.login). ¿Podrías poner el código con el que has intentado capturar la excepción?

Comment: lo que puse del login fue para obtener los datos de visualización en el print nada mas para eso pero pues lo puedo quitar como son parte del reporte

Comment: Gracias. Ahora veo también la creación de la instancia de `FTP`, que no estaba antes. Redactando.

Comment: el error de ftp es: ftplib.error_perm: 530 Login incorrect. Un compañero del trabajo me dijo que si se pudiera hacer por banderas seria util lo que arroje de la instruccion ftp.login pero no sabe de python

Comment: Mira mi respuesta por si es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás preguntando el usuario fuera del bucle, por lo que si el usuario o la contraseña es incorrecta sólo volverá a preguntarte la contraseña. Además, al no tener tu código completo entiendo que dentro del `try` no tienes la conexión, por lo que el bucle `while` no se repetirá porque no se generará una excepción únicamente por introducir un texto con `getpass`:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import getpass

IP = input("Direccion IP: ")
ftp = FTP(IP)
print("Conectado a ", IP)
while True:
  try:
    usu = input("Usuario: ")
    psw = getpass.getpass("Contrasena: ")
    print(ftp.login(user=usu, passwd=psw))
    break
  except:
    print("Contraseña incorrecta")
print("Todo correcto")
ftp.quit()
```

En definitiva, lo que debe repetirse cada vez que se produzca una excepción durante la autenticación es el siguiente bloque:

```
    usu = input("Usuario: ")
    psw = getpass.getpass("Contrasena: ")
    print(ftp.login(user=usu, passwd=psw))
```

Comment: Gracias!! me funciono la verdad aun estoy trabajando como tal con python y no cachaba la idea del try y except